# How is data parsed in this 3D piechart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to grasp how the functions in `Donut3D.js` -> http://plnkr.co/edit/g5kgAPCHMlFWKjljUc3j?p=preview handle the inserted data:

Above all, where is it set that the data's `startAngle` is set at 0 degrees?
I want to change it to 45º, then to 135º, 225º and 315º (look at the image above).

[image]

I've located this function:

```
        Donut3D.draw = function(id, data, x /*center x*/, y/*center y*/, 
                rx/*radius x*/, ry/*radius y*/, h/*height*/, ir/*inner radius*/){

            var _data = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {return d.value;})(data);

            var slices = d3.select("#"+id).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
                .attr("class", "slices");              

            slices.selectAll(".innerSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path").attr("class", "innerSlice")
                .style("fill", function(d) { 
                    return d3.hsl(d.data.color).darker(0.7); })
                .attr("d",function(d){ 
                    return pieInner(d, rx+0.5,ry+0.5, h, ir);})
                .each(function(d){this._current=d;});

            slices.selectAll(".topSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path").attr("class", "topSlice")
                .style("fill", function(d) { 
                    return d.data.color; })
                .style("stroke", function(d) { 
                    return d.data.color; })
                .attr("d",function(d){ 
                    return pieTop(d, rx, ry, ir);})
                .each(function(d){this._current=d;});

            slices.selectAll(".outerSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path").attr("class", "outerSlice")
                .style("fill", function(d) { 
                    return d3.hsl(d.data.color).darker(0.7); })
                .attr("d",function(d){ 
                    return pieOuter(d, rx-.5,ry-.5, h);})
                .each(function(d){this._current=d;});

            slices.selectAll(".percent").data(_data).enter().append("text").attr("class", "percent")
                .attr("x",function(d){ 
                    return 0.6*rx*Math.cos(0.5*(d.startAngle+d.endAngle));})
                .attr("y",function(d){ 
                    return 0.6*ry*Math.sin(0.5*(d.startAngle+d.endAngle));})
                .text(getPercent).each(function(d){this._current=d;});              
        }
```

and tried to insert an arc such as :

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r)
        .startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle + Math.PI/2; })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle + Math.PI/2; });
```

but it doesn't produce the desired effects.

> EDIT 1

The first answer helped in rotating the inner pie, by changing:

```
var _data = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
              return d.value;
            })(data);
```

to

```
var _data = d3.layout.pie()
            .startAngle(45*Math.PI/180)
            .endAngle(405*Math.PI/180).sort(null).value(function(d) {
              return d.value;
            })(data);
```

the problem is that now the outer pie gets broken -> http://plnkr.co/edit/g5kgAPCHMlFWKjljUc3j?p=preview

I guess the solution has something to do with the function function `pieOuter(d, rx, ry, h )` and the two `startAngle` and `endAngle` variables, but they work in apparently unpredictable ways.

Thank you

> I know that Pie Charts are bad, especially if in 3D; but this work
>   is part of my thesis where my job is actually demonstrate how
>   PieCharts are Bad! I want to rotate this PieChart in order to show how
>   if the 3D pie Slice is positioned at the top the data shows as less
>   important, or more important if positioned at the bottom. So a 'Evil
>   Journalist' could alter the visual perception of data by simply
>   inclinating and rotating the PieChart!

Comment: Don't bother. Use something else. Pie charts are horrible, even more in 3D. Don't do that. Give our brains a chance. Don't do pie charts, even if your boss asked for them. Give them histograms, data tables, not pie charts. Heck, even numbers spread in a paragraph of text are better than pie charts. Please.

Comment: Ahah thank you so much for your comment, I know what you mean! But this work is part of my thesis where my job is actually demonstrate how PieCharts are Bad! I want to rotate this PieChart in order to show how if the 3D pie Slice is positioned at the top the data shows as less important, or more important if positioned at the bottom...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a corrected function which allows rotation.

First, modify function signature to include rotate variable:

```
Donut3D.draw = function(id, data, x /*center x*/ , y /*center y*/ ,
        rx /*radius x*/ , ry /*radius y*/ , h /*height*/ , ir /*inner radius*/, rotate /* start angle for first slice IN DEGREES */ ) {
```

In the `draw` function, modify angles.  Instead of screwing with `pie` angles, I'd do it to the data directly:

```
_data.forEach(function(d,i){
  d.startAngle += rotate * Math.PI/180; //<-- convert to radians
  d.endAngle += rotate * Math.PI/180;
});
```

Then you need to correct the `pieOuter` function to fix the drawing artifacts:

```
function pieOuter(d, rx, ry, h) {

    var startAngle = d.startAngle,
        endAngle = d.endAngle;

    var sx = rx * Math.cos(startAngle),
      sy = ry * Math.sin(startAngle),
      ex = rx * Math.cos(endAngle),
      ey = ry * Math.sin(endAngle);

    // both the start and end y values are above
    // the middle of the pie, don't bother drawing anything
    if (ey < 0 && sy < 0)
      return "M0,0";

    // the end is above the pie, fix the points
    if (ey < 0){
      ey = 0;
      ex = -rx;
    }
    // the beginning is above the pie, fix the points.
    if (sy < 0){
      sy = 0;
      sx = rx;
    }

    var ret = [];
    ret.push("M", sx, h + sy, "A", rx, ry, "0 0 1", ex, h + ey, "L", ex, ey, "A", rx, ry, "0 0 0", sx, sy, "z");
    return ret.join(" ");

}
```

---

[Here's the full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/McJ1xsBarOR7hTYDM4J5?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works... Yes as you were saying I was trying to modify the `pieOuter` function but I was only able to fix the outer pie with the starting angle at 45º. Could you explain what you did?

Comment: @CrisBenois, see comments in code above.  Essentially I check for the cases where the "outer pie" should not be drawn or where part of it would be drawn above the pie chart.  I then correct these cases before the path is generated.  The original code did this by fixing any angle above 180 degrees to 180 degrees, this will no longer work because with rotation, you'll move past a full circle.

Comment: Ok, right. There's just one problem with your code that occurs if I try to insert a Pie Hole, why?

Comment: @CrisBenois, are you specifying the `inner radius` as a percent?  http://plnkr.co/edit/McJ1xsBarOR7hTYDM4J5?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the default start angle**

Donut3D users d3's pie layout function [here](https://gist.github.com/NPashaP/9994181#file-donut3d-js-L95), which has a [default startAngle of 0](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#startAngle).

If you want to change the start angle, you should modify donut3d.js.

In the first place, you should certainly avoid to use 3d pie/donut charts, if you care about usability and readability of your visualizations - [explained here](http://blog.visual.ly/2ds-company-3ds-a-crowd/).

**Fixing bottom corner layout**

The `endAngle` you are using is not correct, causing the "light blue" slice to overlap the "blue" one. Should be 405 (i.e. 45 + 360) instead of 415.

```
var _data = d3.layout.pie()
  .startAngle(45*Math.PI/180)
  .endAngle(405*Math.PI/180)
```

Then, the "pieOuter" angles calculation should be updated to behave correctly. The arc which doesn't work is the one where `endAngle > 2 * PI`, and the angle computation should be updated for it.

This does the trick (don't ask me why):

```
// fix right-side outer shape
if (d.endAngle > 2 * Math.PI) {
  startAngle = Math.PI / 120
  endAngle = Math.PI/4
}
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wmPnS9XVyQcrNu4WLa0D?p=preview

Comment: Your comment partially worked, but something is missing. See my last edit... ps. I know what you mean! But this work is part of my thesis where my job is actually demonstrate how PieCharts are Bad! I want to rotate this PieChart in order to show how if the 3D pie Slice is positioned at the top the data shows as less important, or more important if positioned at the bottom.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix *one* of the problems with the bottom right corner of the chart.

Comment: Yes my bad, I had figured that out... but still the first slice, the one starting at 45º, doesn't get its depth... why?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the function function `pieOuter(d, rx, ry, h )` and the two `startAngle` and `endAngle` variables, but I can't figure out how to adjust it according to my 45º...